# Some images do not appear in my list on ionic 3

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an object that contains several information of buildings of my city, all the data appear correctly, only some images are not appearing. All images are in .JPG format

In total there are 200 registered buildings

And this is my `Object`

```
 initializeItems() {
    this.items = [
     {id: '1', nome:'Abaéte', rua:'Moacir', cidade:'Capão da Canoa', bairro:'Centro', numero:'396', ano:'1964', aptos:'55', adm:'Adsel', zelador:'Hugo', contato1:'(51) 0 0000 - 0000', contato2: '(51) 0000 - 0000', imagem:'assets/img/Abaete-min.jpg'},
  ];
}
```

And this a imagem exemple on my App local

[image]

And this is my App on my mobile

[image]

This is the path where the first image is stored

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it as follows, make sure that in the image details the file is like .jpg or .JPG this may seem simple, but do a test and you will see that the problem will be corrected.